# C++: Error deleting array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, destructor

I am having some problems when the destructors of my program are called. I have these clases:

- `myModule` is the base class where the array of pointers is.
- `myModule_in` is a subclass that represents a module with input ports (there is a `myModule_out` and a `myModule_inout` that will not be showed here, since it is not necessary).
- `moduleC` is one of the input ports modules (`moduleA` and `moduleB` are `myModule_out` and `myModule_inout`).

myModule:

```
    class myModule
    {
    public:

      myPort* secondary_ins[NUM];

      myModule() {}

      virtual ~myModule()
      {
        for(int i=0; i<NUM; i++)
        {
          if(secondary_ins[i])
            delete secondary_ins[i];
        }
      }

      virtual void connect(myModule &m) = 0;
    };
```

myModule_in:

```
    class myModule_in : public myModule
    {
    public:
      virtual ~myModule_in() {}

      virtual void connect(myModule &m)
      {
        secondary_ins[ins] = new myPort();
        ...
      }

    };
```

moduleC:

```
    class moduleC : public myModule_in
    {
    public:

      moduleC();
      ~moduleC() {}

      void connect_modules() {...}

    };
```

main:

```
    int main(...)
    {
      moduleA mA;
      moduleB mB;
      moduleC mC;
      ...
      mA.connect(mB);
      mB.connect(mC);
      ...
      return 0;
    }
```

This code compiles correctly and works fine, until the end of execution, where I get a segmentation fault at: `delete secondary_ins[i];` being called from `return 0;`. The strange thing is that the other modules' `destructor` are also called and do not have any problem. Maybe there is something wrong with the handling of array of pointers inherited from a base class or something? Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://bit.ly/1dS4wcV

Comment: Oh! Thanks @735Tesla! I never would have thought of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare:

```
myPort* secondary_ins[NUM];
```

nowhere is guaranteed that the array will be `0` initialized. Therefore the test:

```
if(secondary_ins[i])
```

in the destructor might pass even if the element was not initialized with a valid pointer. For an easy fix, just initialize with `0` (prior to C++11) or to `nullptr` (since C++11) the array.

For a *real fix*, just use a combination of `std::vector` or `std::array` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I was just writing that I already tried that before and it wasn't working. But I just realized that I was initializing the array in the wrong place. And here, one more question. I was doing it in `myModule` and it didn't work, so I did it in each of the `moduleX` that I have (and now it does work). Is it ok? Is there a generic way to do that? Thanks again!

Comment: @makeMonday, yes, you use an `std::unique_ptr` that automatically initializes himself to `nullptr`.